# std::thread join - виснет

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Собственно проблема в полном умирании на операции join.
Вызывается из GUI, обработчик `WM_COMMAND`

```
class Test1
{
private:
    bool _IsRun;
    // volatile bool _IsRun; // без изменений
    // std::atomic<bool> _IsRun; // без изменений
    std::thread _thm;

    void Test();
public:
    Test1() : _IsRun(false) {}
    ~Test1() {}

    ...
};


void Test1::Test()
{
   if (_IsRun)
   {
      _IsRun = false;
      if (_thm.joinable())
          _thm.join();
      return;
   }

   _IsRun = true;

   std::thread thw
   {
        [=]()
        {
            while (_IsRun)
            {
               ....
            }
            _IsRun = false;
        }
   };
   _thm = move(thw);
   // std::swap(_thm, thw);
}
```

Понимаю что что-то делаю не так, но не соображу что.

В `detach()` режиме работает как часы.. без `_thm.joinable()` в блоке `if` естественно ..

Upd:

Проблема все же найдена, поскольку в создаваемом потоке присутствуют long-time операции, то помогла проверка `_IsRun` перед каждой из них. Общее впечатление, что если поток "задумался" на довольно продолжительное время во время ожидания (join) в GUI, то из этого состояния GUI просто не выйти.. При прохождении в отладке всего блока потока во время `join` ошибок нет и всё завершается как запланированно. Особенности w10 ?

Всем спасибо кто уделил внимание этому вопросу, закрыть его не имею возможности.

Comment: @Ant, Я догадываюсь что не кончился :) А почему не кончиться? `_IsRun` вне области видимости? Так вроде в детач работает.. В общем буду рад совету

Comment: Идентификаторы, начинающиеся с подчеркивания и символа в верхнем регистре зарезервированы и использовать их для наименования своих переменных не следует.

Comment: Давайте дальше. Как и откуда все это вызывается?

Comment: @Ant, вызывается из GUI, обработчик `WM_COMMAND`

Comment: Это ни о чем не говорит. Где время жизни объекта `Test1`? Где вызов?

Comment: С атомарной переменной и двумя вызовами `Test` этот код должен работать... Собственно я уже проголосовал за закрытие по причине отсутствия воспроизводимого примера.

Comment: `WndProc` -> `WM_COMMAND` -> `Test()` последовательность вызова такова. Класс является хозяином окна приложения.

Comment: Не надо рассказывать, как оно там у вас вызывается, приведите код, воспроизводящий такое поведение прямо в вопросе

Comment: Как это сделать @VTT ? Там 2000+ строк, скелет как это выглядит приведён точно, на текущий момент, внутри треба ничего связанного с bool переменной нет, кроме того что указанно в вопросе.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: А я вот вообще не понимаю как функция Test должна работать. Сначала идёт вызов join, а только потом создаётся поток.

Comment: @vegorov, это функция тригер..

Comment: Я бы не стал считать это особенностью ОС, скорее проблема в коде. ОС крайне редко бывает виновата.

Comment: @ixSci, Да,возможно, но симптомы были появлением окна подождать/закрыть, и из этого состояния уже не было выхода. В коде конечно с этим были проблемы, процесс написания всё-таки, но логика подсказывает - продолжить -должно работать, код то отрабатывает. Ну да бог с ним, проблема леквидированна :)

Answer (score 2):

С чего вы взяли, что "тред кончился"??? Нет, конечно. Ваш `join` потому и "виснет", что тред не кончился и не кончится никогда.

- Если `_IsRun` - глобальная переменная, т.е. доступна функции потока напрямую, то из-за того, что она не объявлена `volatile`, компилятор вправе генерировать код для функции потока в соответствии с логикой "если `_IsRun` изначально был `true`, то устраиваем бесконечный цикл, ибо поменяться `_IsRun` уже никак не может". На это поведение могут влиять барьеры памяти и инструкции, неявно генерирующие такие барьеры, но полный код функции потока вы не привели.
- Если `_IsRun` - локальная переменная, то у вас функция потока захватывает переменные *по значению*, как вы сами явно попросили, т.е. у нее своя внутренняя копия переменной  `_IsRun`. Изменение внешней `_IsRun` никак не влияет на внутреннюю копию, доступную функции потока.

Comment: Вау! точно, `volatile` ! спасибо @Ant

Comment: поправил код, максимально приближен к оригиналу, с `volatile` картина та-же.. к сожалению

Comment: @NewView Объявленной переменной как `volatile` не влияет на то, что чтение и запись переменной из разных потоков без синхронизации приводит к состоянию гонки и является Неопределенным Поведением. Вам нужна атомарная переменная.

Comment: @NewView: Ну начинается... Оказывается, это у нас поля класса...А почему в исходном вопросе не было этой информации?

Comment: Не придал этому значения :)

Comment: Уберите из ответа `volatile`, пожалуйста, Вы прививаете неокрепшим умам неправильные представление о происходящем. Кстати, то, что Вы описали про глобальную переменную неверно. Компилятор не вправе применить подобную трансформацию, т.к. у него нет никаких причин считать, что глобальная переменная нигде не меняется.

Comment: @VTT, попробовал с `std::atomic<bool>` типом, изменений нет.

Comment: @ixSci: Замечание про `volatile`- совершенно правильное, что запросто можно пронаблюдать на практике на том же godbolt. Утверждений, что `volatile` избавляет о синхронизации, я не делал. (Хотя разумно предположить, что на платформе автора эта переменная натурально является атомарной.) Все остальное - совершено верно. Поэтому о каком "неправильные представление о происходящем" вы веде речь - не ясно.

Comment: На каком основании Вы утверждаете, что компилятор может превратить цикл, использующий глобальную переменную, в бесконечный? Это неправда. Это может быть сделано в каком-то очень ограниченном количестве случаев, где компилятор может и доказывает, что она нигде не изменяется, в противном случае он не имеет права. Что касается остального: применение `volatile`, в современном C++ коде, это на 99% ошибка и непонимание, поэтому я не понимаю, зачем его упоминать в ответе. Нет других средств?

Comment: @AnT: Из вашего текста непонятно, что самого по себе volatile в общем случае недостаточно для синхронизации, поэтому у читающих ответ может сложиться неверное впечатление о том, что достаточно проставить volatile, и проблемы с многопоточным доступом уйдут. То, что volatile достаточно для данного случая и для данной платформы, стоит упомянуть отдельно. (Это я расшифровываю замечание ixSci, насколько я его понял.)

Comment: @ixSci: насколько я понимаю, для случая thread-функции весь код потока компилятору доступен, поэтому он имеет право посчитать, что переменную никто в этом потоке не меняет. (А этого по идее достаточно.)

Comment: @VladD, код потока может вызывать функции, который находятся в других объектных файлах, в которых эта переменная может меняться. Т.е. любая функция, код которой не виден в текущей единице трансляции, и компилятор ничего больше не может делать. Да, он может выполнить межобъектный анализ после линковки и всё-такое прочее, но это уже какие-то очень академические размышления. Кто реально этим занимается и ради чего?

Comment: @ixSci: В thread-функции вполне могут быть лишь вызовы библиотечных функций, семантику которых копмилятор имеет право знать наперёд. Ну и я всё же говорю не о конкретной имплементации компилятора, а о стандарте языка.

Comment: @VladD, в стандарте тем более нет ничего подобного. Есть только as-if правило. Что касается библиотечных функций и «имеет право знать наперёд», не означает, что он будет выполнять подобную «оптимизацию». Зачем лезть в оптимизацию глобальных переменных, потенциально ломая программу, когда в этом мало смысла? Я понимаю, что в теоретических разговорах можно далеко зайти, но кто и когда такое делает на практике?

Comment: @ixSci: Да, я именно к as-if-правилу и вёл :) Согласно нему, компилятор имеет право считать цикл бесконечным. А по поводу того, зачем продвинутые оптимизации — ну так раньше UB-based-оптимизации тоже казались блажью, но сейчас они вполне работают.

Comment: @VladD, да на каком основании он имеет право считать цикл бесконечным? Откуда вы это берёте? Он **обязан доказать**, что эта переменная нигде не изменяется. Какой компилятор проводит такой анализ? Насколько глубок этот анализ? Каковы его ограничения? Что кроме домыслов есть в подобных утверждениях? Я напоминаю, что это ответ на конкретный вопрос, почему у человека не работает код, а не академическая дискуссия в духе «а что если».

Comment: @VladD, давайте рассмотрим этот вопрос даже с чисто теоретической точки зрения. Допустим ответ Ant верный и компилятор действительно оптимизировал цикл, т.к. доказал, что переменная никогда не изменяется. Что тогда даст `volatile`? Ничего, переменная-то не меняется, значит правильный ответ будет такой: «Вы не изменяете переменную нигде». А если она меняется, то компилятор не имел права проводить такую оптимизацию. А если она меняется в другом потоке, то привет data race и UB, хоть с `volatile` хоть без него. Тут с какой стороны не посмотри, этот ответ просто неверен.

Comment: @ixSci: ну, компилятор имеет право заменить цикл на бесконечный, если он видит, что условие цикла не меняется _в данном потоке_ (а в коде ТС так и есть, вроде бы, никаких внешних функций никто не вызывает, кроме библиотечных). А вот насчёт volatile я против, и написал об этом в комментарии AnT выше.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92454/discussion-between-ixsci-and-vladd).

Answer (score 1):

Во первых нужно захватывать не по значению, а по ссылке. Вы в потоке просто копию _IsRun сделали. Копия изменения оригинала не видет.
Во вторых std::atomic нужно. Иначе datarace. Если переменная не atomic (допустим даже компилятор ничего не оптимизировал), некоторое время после присваивания, разные ядра (соответственно разные потоки) могут видеть разные значения в переменной.